# How do I create an Excel workbook object in PeopleTools 8.54?

Tags: peoplesoft

I'm working on a project to write invoices to an excel workbook in PeopleSoft 9.2 using PeopleTools 8.54. In our old version (8.49) we did this:

```
&oWorkApp_Inv = CreateObject("COM", "Excel.Application");
&oWorkApp_Inv.DisplayAlerts = "False";
&oWorkBook_Inv = ObjectGetProperty(&oWorkApp_Inv, "Workbooks");
```

Doing the same in 8.54, I get an error that the application class COM is not found. I've researched through PeopleBooks and it suggested doing exactly what I'm doing, even with COM as the class. What can I do to fix this, and in what package can I find COM?

Answer (score 0):

The two requirements for using the COM object are:

1. The server is running Windows
2. Excel is installed on the server

I created an App Engine is 8.54.13 and it ran successfully on my PSNT process scheduler.

```
Local object &excel;
&excel = CreateObject("COM", "Excel.Application");
&excel.quit();
```